# How can I pass Batch Job parameters to my batch job without using CommandLineRuner?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job which should run at the start up of spring boot app and spring boot app must shut down as soon as the batch job finishes.

I have covered the above scenario by using `spring.batch.job.enabled = true` property in application.yml file.

It ran fine in the starting but since few last runs I am getting below error:

> org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException: A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters={}. If you want to run this job again, change the parameters.

Now, I don't want to use CommandLineRunner which would have let me pass the JobParameters while running the job using JobLauncher. This batch job will run with in a container and should get triggered as soon as the container runs.

My batch job should run as soon as the spring boot apps runs and the app must shut down once the batch job finishes.

I am not sure if I can pass the Job parameters without using CommandLineRunner or not. If I can, can someone point me to the right direction?

My BatchConfiguration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Component
public class BatchConfiguration{

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    JobRepository jobRepository;


    @Bean
    public JobLauncher asyncJobLauncher() throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }


    @Bean
    public Job loadDataFromIodsIcOutbound(DataListener listener, Step inboundStep) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("jobName")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .flow(inboundStep)
                .end()
                .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The messages says:

> A job instance already exists and is complete

It is not an error. It means only that your job has been already executed and was successful. This is the default behavior of a Spring Batch job and should prevent running jobs more then once without changing any parameters.

If your use case is different and you want be able to start the same job again then you can change this default setting by adding this line to your step builder:

```
.allowStartIfComplete(true)
```

To start the Spring Batch job programmatically with specific parameters you can follow this steps:

1. disable automatic start

```
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
```

2. implement ApplicationRunner and add your job parameters

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BatchApplication implements ApplicationRunner {
    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    @Autowired
    Job job;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        log.info("Spring Batch starting.");
        JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("jobName", "MyJobName")
                .addLocalDateTime("currentTime", LocalDateTime.now())
                .toJobParameters();
        jobLauncher.run(job, params);
        log.info("Spring Batch done.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BatchApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This way you Spring Application will run the batch with specified parameters and exit. (Assuming it has no dependencies to Spring Web or MVC or scheduled jobs in which cases it will continue running).

Comment: Is there a way to pass Job Parameters other than passing them through CommandLineRunner and Job Launcher. This batch job will be executed when ECS will execute the container having this jar.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure if I can pass the Job parameters without using CommandLineRunner or not. If I can, can someone point me to the right direction?

You can pass job parameters to your spring boot app on the command line as key/value pairs:

```
java -jar- myjob.jar name=foo
```

Comment: I want to include CurrentTime and the job name to Job parameter list. Can I do that inside beforeJob method of JobExecutionListener?
This batch job will be executed when ECS will execute the container having this jar.

Comment: Passing parameters in `JobExecutionListener#beforeJob` is too late. don't you know the job name beforehand? So you pass it in the command line as argument: `java -jar- myjob.jar jobName=foo`? And why should you pass the job name as a parameter? Are you having multiple jobs in the same jar? If yes, I really recommend not doing that. For the current time, what about something like a variant of `java -jar- myjob.jar time=$(date)`?